# How to transform to lowercase a value in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, case-insensitive

In the SQLite database, I have stored all values in uppercase.

How can I select the specified value in the database using lower case?

Answer (score 16):

For anyone else that arrived here from Google looking how to select **as** upper case in SQLite, as expected, this will work:

```
sqlite> SELECT UPPER("Hello, WORLD!");
HELLO, WORLD!
```

https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#upper

Answer (score 14):

SQLite has [a `LOWER` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) for this:

```
sqlite> SELECT LOWER("Hello, WORLD!");
hello, world!
```

> The lower(X) function returns a copy of string X with all ASCII characters converted to lower case. The default built-in lower() function works for ASCII characters only. To do case conversions on non-ASCII characters, load the ICU extension.